# Error when using the Benjamini-Hochberg false discovery rate in R after Wilcoxon Rank

Tags: r, bioinformatics, p-value

I have carried out a Wilcoxon rank sum test to see if there is any significant difference between the expression of 598019 genes between three disease samples vs three control samples. I am in R.

When I see how many genes have a p value < 0.05, I get 41913 altogether. I set the parameters of the Wilcoxon as follows;

```
wilcox.test(currRow[4:6], currRow[1:3], paired=F, alternative="two.sided", exact=F, correct=F)$p.value
```

(This is within an apply function, and I can provide my total code if necessary, I was a little unsure as to whether alternative="two.sided" was correct).

However, as I assume correcting for multiple comparisons using the Benjamini Hochberg False Discovery rate would lower this number, I then adjusted the p values via the following code
   pvaluesadjust1 <- p.adjust(pvalues_genes, method="BH")

Re-assessing which p values are less than 0.05 via the below code, I get 0!

```
p_thresh1 <- 0.05
names(pvaluesadjust1) <- rownames(gene_analysis1)
output <- names(pvaluesadjust1)[pvaluesadjust1 < p_thresh1]
length(output)
```

I would be grateful if anybody could please explain, or direct me to somewhere which can help me understand what is going on!

Thank-you
(As an extra question, would a t-test be fine due to the size of the data, the Anderson-Darling test showed that the underlying data is not normal. I had far less genes which were less than 0.05 using this statistical test rather than Wilcoxon (around 2000).

Comment: Hi Alice, can you add a few example of your dataset (just few genes) in order we tried your code on it ? Also, if you want to do differential expression analysis on thousands of genes, you can maybe take a look on recognized R packages that can do that. As example, you have `EdgeR`, `DESeq` or `voom-limma`. (as example of it: https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/workflows/vignettes/RnaSeqGeneEdgeRQL/inst/doc/edgeRQL.html and https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/workflows/vignettes/rnaseqGene/inst/doc/rnaseqGene.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wilcoxon is a parametric test based on ranks. If you have only 6 samples, the best result you can get is rank 2,2,2 in disease versus 5,5,5 in control, or vice-versa.

For example, try the parameters you used in your test, on these random values below, and you that you get the same p.value 0.02534732.

```
wilcox.test(c(100,100,100),c(1,1,1),exact=F, correct=F)$p.value
wilcox.test(c(5,5,5),c(15,15,15),exact=F, correct=F)$p.value
```

So yes, with 598019 you can get 41913 < 0.05, these p-values are not low enough and with FDR adjustment, none will ever pass.

You are using the wrong test. To answer your second question, a t.test does not work so well because you don't have enough samples to estimate the standard deviation correctly. Below I show you an example using DESeq2 to find differential genes

```
library(zebrafishRNASeq)
data(zfGenes)
# remove spikeins
zfGenes = zfGenes[-grep("^ERCC", rownames(zfGenes)),]
head(zfGenes)
                   Ctl1 Ctl3 Ctl5 Trt9 Trt11 Trt13
ENSDARG00000000001  304  129  339  102    16   617
ENSDARG00000000002  605  637  406   82   230  1245
```

First three are controls, last three are treatment, like your dataset. To validate what I have said before, you can see that if you do a wilcoxon.test, the minimum value is 0.02534732

```
all_pvalues = apply(zfGenes,1,function(i){
wilcox.test(i[1:3],i[4:6],exact=F, correct=F)$p.value
})
min(all_pvalues,na.rm=T)
# returns 0.02534732
```

So we proceed with DESeq2

```
library(DESeq2)
#create a data.frame to annotate your samples
DF = data.frame(id=colnames(zfGenes),type=rep(c("ctrl","treat"),each=3))
# run DESeq2
dds = DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(zfGenes,DF,~type)
dds = DESeq(dds)
summary(results(dds),alpha=0.05)

out of 25839 with nonzero total read count
adjusted p-value < 0.05
LFC > 0 (up)       : 69, 0.27%
LFC < 0 (down)     : 47, 0.18%
outliers [1]       : 1270, 4.9%
low counts [2]     : 5930, 23%
(mean count < 7)
[1] see 'cooksCutoff' argument of ?results
[2] see 'independentFiltering' argument of ?results
```

So you do get hits which pass the FDR cutoff. Lastly we can pull out list of significant genes

```
res = results(dds)
res[which(res$padj < 0.05),]
```